# Django settings LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL dynamic based on language

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/foo/bar/' and I am on http://127.0.0.1/en/login/ and I login successfully. I will be redirected to http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar/ resulting in losing the language prefix. What should I do in order to maintain the language code in the url? Of course, I want all the other languages codes work and also the default one just like that:

```
http://127.0.0.1/en/login/ -> http://127.0.0.1/en/foo/bar/
http://127.0.0.1/login/ -> http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar/
http://127.0.0.1/ro/login/ -> http://127.0.0.1/ro/foo/bar/
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can extend Django's [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) and override the `get_success_url` method.

Something like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.utils.translation import get_language



class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        # lang = get your language from the URL (it'd be helpful if you post your URLs in order to help better) or you can use like this:
        lang = get_language()
        url = '{}/{}/login'.format(yourbaseurl, lang)
        return url
```

Comment: It would be quite over the hand doing like that, because I have both the default login flow and the python-social-auth app. So that means I would have to modify 2 separate files for the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Django auth and the `LoginView` from the framework, you can parametrize the URL to redirect to after logging in. The `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is a fallback when it is not specified.

The `LoginView` attribute is called `next`. The `next` url can be set using a parameter from the previous page like `?next=<your_url>`. Just don't forget to sanitize it using `is_safe_url()` from `django.utils.http`.

Comment: This seems like a mess for me, because I would have to make changes in the templates themselves and I do not want that.